# Where to upload my webpage for free

Tags: html

How should I upload my webpage online for free, I have few Html, css, JS file no server side code .
can anyone recommend any? I tried Google searching but I didn't find any appropriate.
I should be able to modify the web page later on after uploading.

Comment: This site is not suitable for such questions.

Comment: Please don't ask off-topic questions here. You may refer to other StackExchange forums such as "Webmasters".

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 Free tier would work for the first year.

Check out: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

and here is the pricing information: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/